# How to avoid name clashes in cmake subprojects?

Tags: cmake

So I have setup a metaproject, which means I have one directory (the root directory) containing multiple subdirectories, each of which is a cmake project (with a valid cmakelists). The cmakelists in the root directory imports the subprojects using the cmake add_subdirectory command.

Each subproject defines it's own targets (libraries and executables) as well as targets "check" which executes the test suite for that project and "docs" which runs doxygen.

My problem is that CMake does not understand that the check and docs targets are local to each project, and therefore complains about name clashes.

So my question is, is there any way to get cmake to understand that these targets are local to each project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake doesn't allow duplicate target names.  The rationale is provided in the [docs for policy `CMP0002`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/policy/CMP0002.html):

> - Unique names may be referenced unambiguously both in CMake
>     code and on make tool command lines.
> - Logical names are used by Xcode and VS IDE generators
>     to produce meaningful project names for the targets.

Your could try setting `CMP0002` to `OLD` (done via `cmake_policy(SET CMP0002 OLD)`) which would at least get rid of the CMake error, but I'd recommend against that - it certainly won't work for MSVC/Xcode.

The only option I can see short of hand-coding unique names would be to write a CMake function which generates a unique name per "check" target - for example it could append the name of the target which is being checked, yielding names like `check_my_lib_one`, `check_my_exe_one`, etc.

This function could also be used to collect a list of all registered `check_<Target>` instances and add them to a single target called `check` which would invoke each subordinate `check_<Target>`, so running `make check` runs them all.

Comment: Well, I was looking for something like a "one namespace per project" kind of solution, but that doesn't seem to exist in cmake, so I will use your solution, thanks!

Comment: @Abstract-Sky technically, you could use a namespace convention by yourself. For example prefixing all a project's targets by the project name.

Comment: @ibizaman That's whay I ended up doing, using a macro to automate adding the prefix.

Comment: Is there non automatic prefix which could be enabled with no need to rename anything?